# Cannot use a custom devise strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise to add an authentication layer on my rails application. I have to setup a LDAP authentification. So I created my own strategy, I literally followed this [wiki article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Authenticate-via-LDAP). However, I got this error:

```bash
11: from /home/mcdostone/X/app/models/user.rb:3:in `<main>'
10: from /home/mcdostone/X/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
...
/home/mcdostone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Devise::Models::LdapAuthenticatable (NameError)
```

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :ldap_authenticatable
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that wiki page is quite outdated.
You now need a `LdapAuthenticatable` module in `Devise::Models` as well as `Devise::Strategies`.

`config/initializers/ldap_authenticatable.rb`

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module LdapAuthenticatable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    end
  end

  module Strategies
    class LdapAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      ... same as before ...
    end
  end
end
```

I really recommend you to use this [gem](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable) instead, since there will be many tweaks you will need to make it work well.

Comment: I wanted to use this gem but It's not only a simple LDAP authentication, I need to add more things. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sree for your help. It's working properly now! Here my solution:

```ruby
# config/initializers/ldpa_authenticatable.rb

module Devise
  module Models
    module LdapAuthenticatable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    end
  end

  module Strategies
    class LdapAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      # This method first checks if the user is present in the database.
      # After that, we authenticate the user thanks to the LDAP server
      def authenticate!
        if params[:user]
          user = User.find_by(username: username)
          if user.nil?
            return fail(:invalid_login)
          else
            ldap = Ldap.client
            ldap_username = Ldap.get_login(username)
            puts ldap_username.inspect
            ldap.authenticate ldap_username, password
            if ldap.bind
              success!(user)
            else
              return fail(:invalid_login)
            end
          end
        end
      end

      def username
        params[:user][:username]
      end

      def password
        params[:user][:password]
      end
    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:ldap_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::LdapAuthenticatable)
Devise.add_module(:ldap_authenticatable,
                  route: :session, ## This will add the routes, rather than in the routes.rb
                  strategy: true,
                  controller: :sessions,
                  model: "ldap_authenticatable")
```